# Using screenrc, how can I make `C-a c` open a new window at the current window's working directory?

Tags: gnu-screen, working-directory

Using screenrc, how can I make `C-a c` open a new window at the current window's working directory? By default it appears to open the new window at the working directory at the time the original screen session is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517414/how-to-make-gnu-screen-start-a-new-window-at-the-current-working-directory), I think this should work:

```
bind c stuff "screen -X chdir \$PWD; screen^M"
```

I'll go try it on my remote shell and report back if it works for me.

edit: Yup, it works. The first "bind" command is actually not needed.

Comment: I read that answer, but thought stuff was a placeholder for something else. What does the ^M in your code sample above?

Comment: This has done it, but without the extra ^M, perhaps this was from copy-pasting?

Answer (score 6):

By default, `screen` also binds `C-a C-c` to create a new window, so you might want to add another line to your `.screenrc` to handle this case:

```
bind c stuff "screen -X chdir \$PWD;screen^M"
bind ^c stuff "screen -X chdir \$PWD;screen^M"
```

---

Clarification about how this command works:

1. `stuff` puts its argument string [directly into the current window](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_11.html#IDX134):

   > Command: `stuff string`
   >
   > Stuff the string `string` in the input buffer of the current window.
2. `screen -X chdir \$PWD` tells screen to execute the command `chdir`, which changes its operational directory (where new screen windows will start) to the environment variable `$PWD`, which contains the current working directory. This is impossible to do within `.screenrc` alone; therefore, manipulating the input buffer with `stuff` is necessary.
3. The `screen` command within an already running `screen` creates a new window just like `C-a C-c`.
4. `^M` generates a carriage return, which tells the shell to execute the command which is now in the buffer. Without it, you would have to press `enter` (or `C-m`, of course).

Consequently, this bind will leave cruft like this in the window you execute it in:

```
user@host:~/directory$ screen -X chdir $PWD;screen
user@host:~/directory$
```

Comment: Any Idea why the ^M isn't necessary?

Comment: It _is_ necessary, so that a carriage return is generated at the end of the `stuff` string.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this work in a named screen session? http://superuser.com/questions/1038576/gnu-screen-open-new-window-in-working-directory-of-current-window-in-a-named @MattEckert

Comment: This doesn't work if a long-running process is running in the current window

Answer (score 1):

Here's a copy of [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517414/how-to-make-gnu-screen-start-a-new-window-at-the-current-working-directory/33241923#33241923) to [a similar question on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517414/how-to-make-gnu-screen-start-a-new-window-at-the-current-working-directory/33241923):

> To make screen open a new tab/window in the current directory, you can
>   add the following code to your **`.screenrc`** file:
>
> ```
> bind c stuff "screen bash^M"
> ```
>
> This will cause the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>
>   command to open new tabs/windows in the directory of the current
>   window/tab.
>
> **Note:** You must ensure that `screen` does **not** start a [login shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Shell) by
>   default because that will cause the shell start in the default
>   directory for a login shell rather than the current directory. This
>   means that In your **`.screenrc`** file, your `shell` command cannot
>   include a dash ('-') character.
>
> For example, this is wrong (i.e. it will start a login shell):
>
> ```
> shell -$SHELL
> ```
>
> But this is right (i.e. it will **not** start a login shell):
>
> ```
> shell $SHELL
> ```
>
> **Note 2:** Unfortunately, this method does not behave exactly like the default new window/tab command in `screen`. Instead, it writes the
>   command to the current window and executes it to create the new
>   window/tab, so it will not work during some long running shell
>   process. In other words, this keyboard shortcut can only be executed
>   whenever normal shell commands can be executed.
>
> **Note 3:** If you want `screen` to open new windows/tabs in the current directory **and** open **a login shell**, you can add the
>   following code to your **`.screenrc`** file:
>
> ```
> bind c stuff "screen bash -l^M"
> ```

Comment: About Note 2, Is there a way to overcome this? after sending a command, such as compiling huge sources, I'd like to create new windows and want to do other things. It is impossible now. I have tried to find a solution but everytime end up failing. this answer only touch this issue. so I add comments.